# Fastest way to convert a string with many integers into a list distinct integers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string that contains many integers separated with commas.
I am trying to convert this string (which is something like this `csv_data = "1,23,543,12,423,534,76,32,765,23,12,1,43,213,6,5"`)

into a list of distinct integer values.
`csv_values = [1,23,543,12,423,534,76,32,765,23,12,1,43,213,6,5]`

The first idea that i tried was a for loop, but i know that is not the fastest way to make the conversion

```
l = []
for ch in csv_data:
    if ch != ',':
       l.append(int(ch))
```

any ideas?

Comment: u want this done via plain python or pandas?

Comment: i would like to see both if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using standard lib and pandas.

```
from ast import literal_eval
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

string = "1,23,543,12,423,534,76,32,765,23,12,1,43,213,6,5"

list(literal_eval(string))

[1, 23, 543, 12, 423, 534, 76, 32, 765, 23, 12, 1, 43, 213, 6, 5]

pd.eval(string)

array([1, 23, 543, 12, 423, 534, 76, 32, 765, 23, 12, 1, 43, 213, 6, 5],
      dtype=object)
```

you can then use `np.unique` or just `set` to get the distinct integers.

```
np.unique(pd.eval(string))
array([1, 5, 6, 12, 23, 32, 43, 76, 213, 423, 534, 543, 765], dtype=object)
```

or

```
list(set(literal_eval(string)))

[32, 1, 5, 6, 423, 43, 12, 76, 213, 534, 23, 765, 543]
```

note, `np.unique` will sort your values.

some naive timings,

```
string2 = string * 1000

%%timeit

list(set(literal_eval(string2)))

34 ms ± 1.55 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

```
%%timeit

np.unique(pd.eval(string2))

494 ms ± 12.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to firstly convert it to a list

```
def Convert(string): 
       li = list(string.split("-")) 
       return li
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you have it in a string, you can use `[int(x) for x in csv_data.split(',')]`
- If the data actually comes from a file, use one of the already-existing functions to read a csv file, either the [built-in `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or the [Pandas `read_csv` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).